# Is it possible to store Google Maps api data into data base

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I've been working on a project involved with google maps api.
Basically, every time the program runs sends requests to the google maps api, which could become a problem later.
Is it possible to store all this information in a database and then, instead of making the exact same request to Google, just pulling it from the DB?

This is the Javascript code:

```
/********************************************************************/
function initMap()
{
  /********************************************************************/
  var routeTesting =
  [
    {lat: 15.5056524, lng: -88.0244702},
      {lat: 15.5057297, lng: -88.0253025},
      {lat: 15.5059322, lng: -88.0275617},
      {lat: 15.5077225, lng: -88.0290227},
      {lat: 15.5118536, lng: -88.0242649},
    {lat: 15.5136369, lng: -88.0217633}
  ];
  var routeTesting2 =
  [
    {lat: 15.5056524, lng: -88.0244702},
      {lat: 15.5057297, lng: -88.0253025},
      {lat: 15.5008444, lng: -88.0205006},
      {lat: 15.4938188, lng: -88.0211481},
      {lat: 15.4932665, lng: -88.0230147},
    {lat: 15.5136369, lng: -88.0217633}
  ];
  var c =
  [
    "#000000",
    "#FF0011"
  ];

  var testing = false;
  var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(routeTesting[1]);
  var currentDestiny;
  var currentLocationMarkers = [];
  var currentLocationMarker;
  var currentDestinyMarker;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    polylineOptions: {
      strokeColor: "#000"
    }
  });

  var map;
  var mapOptions =
  {
    center: currentLocation,
    zoom: 18
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

  routeCreate(routeTesting, c[0]); //displays testing route.
  routeCreate(routeTesting2, c[1]); //displays second testing route.
  /********************************************************************/
  function routeCreate(r, c)
  {
    var orig = r[1];
    var dest = r[1];
    var waypoints = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < r.length - 1; i++)
    {
      waypoints.push({location: r[i], stopover: false});
    }
    var request =
    {
        origin: orig,
      waypoints: waypoints,
      optimizeWaypoints: false,
        destination: dest,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };
    var directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      polylineOptions: {
        strokeColor: c
      }
    });
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, sstatus){
      if(sstatus == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
      {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
        }
      else
      {
        alert("Error :'(");
      }
    });
    directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
  }
  /********************************************************************/
  function createMarker(coor)
  {
    var marker = new google.maps.LatLng(coor[0], coor[1]);
    var testLoc1Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: marker,
      map: map,
      title: 'Test Marker'
    });
  }
  /********************************************************************/
  map.addListener('click', function(event)
  {
    addMarker(event.latLng);
  });
  /********************************************************************/
  function addMarker(location)
  {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
    currentLocationMarkers.push(marker);
    if(currentLocationMarkers.length > 1)
    {
      for (var i = 0; i < currentLocationMarkers.length; i++)
      {
        currentLocationMarkers[i].setMap(null);
      }
      currentLocationMarkers = [];
      addMarker(location);
    }
    else {
      //checkClosestWaypoint();
    }
  }
  /********************************************************************/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO, You cannot if it is not for performance

Here is a copy/paste of the relevent c & d sub of 10.5

> No use of Content outside the Service. You will not use any Content outside of the Service except as expressly permitted to do so in Subsection (d). For example, you will not export or save the Content to a third party’s platform or service.
>
> No caching or storage. You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store
>   any Content to be used outside the Service, except that you may store
>   limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the
>   performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency
>   (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking
>   usage), and only if such storage: is temporary (and in no event more
>   than 30 calendar days); is secure; does not manipulate or aggregate
>   any part of the Content or Service; and does not modify attribution in
>   any way.

See, 10.5 c & d for the long answer
https://developers.google.com/maps/terms-20180207

Comment: "except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation "... which surely is exactly what the OP wants

Comment: you are right, I edited my answer to highlight the performance valid reason

Comment: all good, looks like quite strict rules i wouldent of thought existed, not that i have dealt with this particular API.

Comment: Or otherwise you can have your own map data using Open Street Map [Nominatim] Server. You can setup it in your environment in your Own Server. https://www.openstreetmap.org/. For more information read Nominatim - OpenStreetMap Wiki at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

Answer (score 0):

You can make another Ajax function to save passed data to the database using php file. For an example, if you want to save latitude & longitude in the database, just use below code to send latitude & longitude to savedata.php file.

```
function save_data(latitude, longitude){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "savedata.php",
        data: {'latitude':latitude, 'longitude':longitude},
        cache: false,
        success:  function(data){
        alert("Settings has been updated successfully.");
        }
    });
}
```

You need to call above function inside your Google API code section.

```
save_data(latitude, longitude);
```

by passing **latitude, longitude** values.

Then in the savedata.php file you can get those latitude, longitude values as post variable. So you can easiliy save them in to the database.

savedata.php

```
<?php
// You database connection settings herre
include('database_settings.php');

if(isset($_POST['latitude']) && isset($_POST['longitude'])){
    // Write your insert query here
}
?>
```